# Creating RDS instance from exported snapshot on S3

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I want to give an intern a snapshot of my RDS DB (MySQL) so that he can play around and do some analytics with the copy. He has a valid IAM user on my AWS account.

I don't want to use a read replica; I want this to be an isolated copy of my DB.

I'm thinking the flow could be:

1. Create a snapshot of my RDS and export it to an S3 bucket
2. Give him access to the S3 bucket
3. Somehow, give him access to create his own (isolated) RDS instances, but *not* be able to see or modify my RDS instances (production)
4. That way, he might be able to create a new RDS from the snapshot in the S3 bucket

I *think* this is a viable sequence of events (correct me if I'm wrong!) but where I'm fuzzy is the last 2 steps, giving him *just enough* RDS access (not sure what the permissions/ACLs would be) to create his own RDS instances, and how to create those instances from the exported snapshots stored on S3. Does anybody have any ideas here? Ideally, I could limit the size of the RDS instances he can create as well, or limit them in other ways so that he can't send billing through the roof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't conditionally allow the internee to see their database and not yours. Conditional listing policy is not applicable here.
2. You can set Tags on your RDS and set IAM policy to not modify/delete specific tags, or vice versa. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_iam-tags.html)
3. You may skip exporting snapshot to your S3 all along and allow your internee to create DB from the snapshot available on RDS dashboard.
4. You can set limits on instance class by adding conditions for RDS available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html). But you won't be able to limit the size and number of DB's they may create.

For the sake of safety and ease, if it's a one time effort, I would suggest you to create DB from production snapshot once for yourself and provide admin credentials for this new DB to the intern. If it's repetitive effort, create an [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/) bash script that creates new DB with latest snapshot and deletes previous one if it exists, that script will be executed by you.

But if you choose to provide AWS Access:

- Don't provide any Delete access.
- Provide Conditional Create, Modify access based on `aws:ResourceTag/${TagKey}`, `rds:DatabaseClass`.
- Provide limited List, Read access.

Comment: Thanks @amsh (+1) -- I _do_ want to update his RDS instance with a new snapshot (taken each day from my prod RDS instance), so I like your idea about using the AWS CLI. Is there a way to automate this from a Lambda or something similar, in AWS? That is, a nightly/cronjob to rebuild his RDS from a particular snapshot? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you will need a Lambda function with the language of your choice (python, js etc.) Use AWS SDK to do the same steps you want to do manually. SDK has same functions as AWS cli. Provide Lambda Function an IAM Role with the required access.
Set CloudWatch Event to trigger that Lambda Function based on some cron expression

Comment: Thanks again (and +1), and sorry, to be clear on the IAM permissions: it _sounds_ like you are saying I can add a tag (say, `backup`) to my production RDS, and then somehow configure it so that the intern does not have permission to delete or modify it or its snapshots? And it also _sounds_ like you are saying that I can set IAM permissions to only allow the intern to create his own RDS from a specific snapshot resource? Can you confirm or clarify for me? Thanks again!

Comment: With tag based policies in place and your RDS DB tagged, intern won't be able to modify/delete your DB. While with create and read permissions, he will be able to create his own DB from snapshot